# Trigger for unique column

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to create a trigger in which, it is not possible to add or update an entry if it has a previous entry with one field set to one value.

Let's put an example:

Given the following table:

```
id  name          type,    description, (some other fields)
 1  'Manuel'      'HUMAN'  ...
 2  'Manuel'      'DOG'    ...
 3  'Other name'  'HUMAN'  ...
```

If I want to add a new entry like this:

```
insert into table_name (name, type, description,...)
values ('Manuel', 'HUMAN', 'first entry', ...)
```

It should not work since it should not be allowed to add another `HUMAN` type for the name `Manuel`.

But, it should be allowed to do this:

```
insert into table_name (name, type, description, ...) values ('Manuel', 'DOG', 'another description')
```

So, basically the idea is that, for each name, it should be only allowed one `HUMAN` entry type.

I created this trigger, but it is not working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TABLE_TYPE_REL
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_name
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.TYPE = 'HUMAN')
declare @check int

select @check = count(*)
from table_name as f
where f.type = 'HUMAN'

if @check <> 0
begin
    rollback transaction
    raiserror('Only one name, human is allowed.', 16, 1)
end
```

Any clue?

Comment: i think you'd want a unique constraint over a trigger

Comment: Isn't this overkill? Wouldn't a unique constraint on (name, type) be sufficient and more robust than a trigger?

Comment: Why are you showing MS SQL-Server code for an Oracle question?

Comment: @Boneist - unique (name, type) does not meet the requirement. The OP wants unique (name) for the subset of rows where type = HUMAN; he doesn't care if (Manuel, DOG) is duplicated in the table.

Comment: @mathguy Ah, good point; I missed that bit of the question. In which case, I still think that a trigger is overkill, and a function based index is the way to go - e.g. Justin's answer.

Comment: @Boneist - lol, just what I was writing at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tags say that you are using Oracle.  The trigger code you posted is for SQL Server.  I will assume that you are actually using Oracle and the reason your trigger "isn't working" is that it's written in the wrong language (as an aside, it's really helpful to include error stacks rather than saying that something "isn't working")

It sounds like you want a function-based index that only includes rows where the `type='HUMAN'`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_one_human
    ON table_name( CASE WHEN type = 'HUMAN'
                        THEN name
                        ELSE null
                    END );
```

Comment: @Manuelarte - as a general principle, think of triggers as "the last resort", tools you will use only when everything else fails. Constraints and indexes are much better choices when you can find a solution using them. Namaste Justin for a simple, elegant and reliable solution.

Comment: @JustinCave thank you for your answer. That's exactly what we want. The only thing that it can happen is that, maybe, the error message we may have it is not 100% readable if we do not fulfill the unique index, right?

Comment: @Manuelarte - If you want to raise an exception with a custom error message, you can always catch the `dup_val_on_index` exception and use `raise_application_error` to raise the custom exception.

Comment: How can we achieve the uniqueness, without creating an index ? Creation of a unique index may be restrictive in certain operations like partition switching in SQL Server ?

Comment: @DhumilAgarwal - Not easily.  If you don't care about creating unique indexes in general, you just want to avoid creating a unique index on the particular table, you could create a materialized view that selected only the rows you want from the source table, set that materialized view to refresh on commit, and then create a unique index on the materialized view.  That's duplicative of storage space, generates more I/O, requires you to have materialized view logs on the base table, etc.  But it does avoid creating a unique index on the table.  I'm not sure why that would be advantageous though.